# Get number of element in array (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have AJAX call

Here is code

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
           // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var emailHTML = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' + result.indexOf(this)+
                    result[i].Email +
                    '<b>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
                    result[i].Name +
                    '</b>' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I need to write element number from `1`, I tried this `result.indexOf(this)`, but it not works

How I can do this?

Comment: why not write `i+1` instead of `result.indexOf(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, you should write something like :

```
var emailHTML = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' + (i + 1) +
                    result[i].Email +
                    '<b>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
                    result[i].Name +
                    '</b>' +
                    '</div>';
```

Just use the value of your variable i incremented in loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the variable **i** with which you are iterating like so:

```
 var emailHTML = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' +(i+1)+
                    result[i].Email +
                    '<b>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
                    result[i].Name +
                    '</b>' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
```

The specific reason for using (i+1) is because i starts its iteration from 0 and you want it from 1.